# How to set up a Django project in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm new in this area so I have a question. Recently, I started working with Python and Django. I installed PyCharm Community edition as my IDE, but I'm unable to create a Django project.

I looked for some tutorials, and there is an option to select "project type", but in the latest version this option is missing. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269574/how-to-run-debug-server-for-django-project-in-pycharm-community-edition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Debug server for Django project in PyCharm Community Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269574/how-to-run-debug-server-for-django-project-in-pycharm-community-edition)

Answer (score 80):

You can simply go to:

```
In Run -> Edit Configurations create new configuration
Script: path_to/manage.py
Script parameters: runserver
```

Answer (score 24):

If you look at the [features edition comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), you will see that only *PyCharm* *Professional* supports the *Django Framework*.

You can set up a project from the command line using the manage.py script and just open it in PyCharm. Then use the terminal to sync, start server etc...

You can use Eclipse PyDev with https://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html. I have not tried it so I cannot say how good or bad it is.

There is a tutorial on setting up a new project [here](http://lowcoupling.com/post/47845431628/creating-a-new-django-project-with-eclipse-py-dev).

[Wingware](https://www.wingware.com/wingide/features/101) also seems to have some Django support.

Comment: So much from free IDE. Can you suggest alternative free IDE for Python/Django?

Comment: @user3676356, I added to my answer.

Comment: +1 for Eclipse with PyDev, It can be a bit of a chore at the start but i love it now. PyDev has Django support as well. Youtube videos how setting up Django projects in Pydev are a very quick way to learn it.

Comment: What happens when Community pyCharm users open Professional pyCharm projects with Django extensions?

Comment: @DaleE.Moore, it would just open it as regular Python files.  The only issue is that Django is not integrated into the IDE, so you'd have to run the Django commands externally, such as `runserver`.

Answer (score 7):

I have met the problems today. At last, I finished it by:

1. Create project in command line
2. Create app in command line
3. Just open the existing files and code in pycharm

The way I use have the benefits:

- don't need by professional pycharm
- code django project in pycharm

Comment: FelisCatus, is this answer still valid for Pycharm Community 2019?

Answer (score 6):

Pycharm integration with Django. Please try below steps for integration.

**1. Add Django plugin inside your python interpreter**

[image]

Click + icon for installation of Django

[image]
Click on the install package, it will take some time for installation.

**2. Check Django installation:**

> create a sample.py file

```
  import django
  print(django.get_version())
```

**3. Open the terminal and entered**

```
django-admin startproject mysite(name of your project)
```

**4. Run Server**

```
cd mysite
python manage.py runserver
```

> You are able to start Django server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

**5. Create the application**

Open the another terminal and entered

```
 cd mysite
 python manage.py startapp webapp(name of your app)
```

Please refer for more detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUeLWSrtcFc

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I use [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to install dependencies, so I will assume you have it installed. Otherwise, follow [these instructions](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/#installing-pipenv). I use Python 3, so I will also use Django 2.

## Using PyCharm 2019.1, 2018.3.1

I can state that it has become pretty simple the way to start a Django project.

1. Open PyCharm, and select `Create New Project`.

[image]

2. Choose Django in the left menu, provide a path and a name for your project. I strongly recommend using `pipenv` to manage your packages. Click on Create.

[image]

That's it. Wait to PyCharm to create a virtual environment, install Django, and and index files. Now you are all set. Click on the play button in upper run corner and you will see the Django launch page you can see at the end of this answer.

## !######################################################!

## Previous versions of PyCharm

First, let's create a project that will have the name of our Django project. I will call this directory `mysite`, and I will navigate inside of it.

```
$ mkdir mysite && cd mysite
```

Second, let's create a virtual environment using `pipenv`:

```
$ pipenv --three
```

Third, open up PyCharm, and click on Open. Browse to `mysite` directory, and click on Open.

[image]
[image]

PyCharm will automatically recognize the virtual environment that you previously created, so if you open a terminal inside PyCharm, you will see the interpreter is actually set.

[image]

Fourth, from the terminal, install Django using pipenv and create a new project called `mysite`

```
$ pipenv install django
$ django-admin startproject mysite .
```

After running this commands your project directory should look like this:

[image]

```
mysite # this is the root project
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── manage.py # this is the Manage script
└── mysite
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py # these are the settings
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Fifth, enable the Django support in `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Django`.

[image]

Check *Enable Django Support*, and provide the *Django project root*, *Settings*, and *Manage script*. Click on Apply and then OK.

[image]

Finally, you have to configure a Django server. Click on `Add Configuration ...` in the upper right.

[image]

Click on the plus sign in the upper left part, and select Django Server.

[image]

Provide a name, check Run browser if you want to open a tab when you click on the play button, and click on Apply and then OK.

[image]

Now you just can click on the play button in the right upper section.

[image]

Congrats! You are all set if you visualize the following page.

[image]

Comment: @AylianCraspa, this question has a tag PyCharm, and I am giving an answer for a version of PyCharm that I am using. I do not use the community edition, and I feel it is kind of disrespectful from your side to downvote my question just because I don't give an answer for your version.

Comment: you surly have but it is not accurate for the question title, we search this online to see how to setup pycharm community edition coz there is lot of posts available on the internet to work with pycharm professional edition.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old but what I will suggest is to use a professional edition with at least a license for educational use. To do it, create an account using your institution email then go [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/community/education/) to apply for it. It'll help you to use professional edition.
But you can also buy a license if you want.