# Can't run django server from Pycharm

Tags: python, django

I recently fromated my computer and installed win 10.
I have installed pycharm and python 3.4 with django 1.8.6 .
Then I loaded a django project, which I had on my computer before formatting it and backed it up on Google Drive.
I can run my app through command line with the command "python manage.py runserver" (I am running this command while I'm in the project path), and it's working very well like that.
But I need to run it through pycharm in order to use the debugger.
I've tried to use the "Edit configuration" button, but with no success.
Any help will be appreciated.
I have attached an image.
Edit configuration window:
[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors? Nothing happens when you start?

Comment: I hit the ok button and still the run/debug buttons are disabled. But I succeeded to figure it out. Apperantly I had to add a new configuration and not to edit the existing one.
Like in this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870365/how-to-setup-django-project-in-pycharm

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to add a new configuration and not to edit the existing one.
I followed the steps from this post:
[How to setup Django project in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870365/how-to-setup-django-project-in-pycharm)