# Django Templates and Apps Not Loading

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, templates, pycharm

The title says most of it. I'm running Unittests.py in PyCharm on a tutorial and my templates folder is nested directly beneath my app folder (superlists/lists/templates/home.html). 
So here's the test I'm running superlists/lists/tests.py:

```
def test_home_page_returns_correct_html(self):
    request = HttpRequest()

    response = home_page(request)
    expected_html = render_to_string('home.html')

    self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expected_html)
```

And here's the code it's being run on (superlists/lists/views.py)

```
def home_page(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

And here's the error:

```
   Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 86, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\superlists\lists\tests.py", line 19, in test_home_page_returns_correct_html
    response = home_page(request)
  File "C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\superlists\lists\views.py", line 8, in home_page
    return render(request, 'home.html')
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 67, in render
    template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 96, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 26, in get_template
    engines = _engine_list(using)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 143, in _engine_list
    return engines.all() if using is None else [engines[using]]
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 110, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 110, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 101, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 31, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 49, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 121, in get_installed_libraries
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs())
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    **raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.**
```

So, I checked two places in settings.py, INSTALLED_APPS and TEMPLATES.

Here's both sections:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'lists',
]
```

and

```
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Here's a short list of things I've tried:
*Changing the source code of `tests.py` and `views.py` to have most combinations of the path to home.html
*Changing the path listed in INSTALLED_APPS and TEMPLATES to have most combinations of varying lengths to the paths of `lists` and `home.html`
*Changing `'DIRS': []` to `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],`

Sidenote:  I've also had to repeatedly put `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=(project directory name).settings` as an environment variable in PyCharm, using the solution to an error, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556499/django-db-settings-improperly-configured-error), because the other solutions didn't work, so, I recognize that my setup may be just a tad buggy.

Comment: Are you able to run tests from the command line? i.e. `python manage.py test`?

Comment: Hmmm.
Curiously, yes, and the tests passed, save for a mark on my string arguments to url being deprecated.
PyCharm community messing with me?

*Or unittest?

Comment: Okay, just a couple more questions: 1. Have you added Django support for your project? See bottom of [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/django.html). and 2. Are you using Django test configuration? See [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html).

Comment: I have not - I'd been using some of the solutions for the community version of Pycharm on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870365/how-to-setup-django-project-in-pycharm), assuming testing frameworks would behave as normal. I supposed incorrectly. 
Time to go back to the CMD, for now.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't related to template, but wrong test configuration in PyCharm.

It seems you are using `Python tests -> Unittests` configuration for your tests, PyCharm provides a specific configuration for `Django tests` (it automatically loads the right django settings).

So follow this steps to configure it:

1. Go to the menu *Run -> Edit Configurations...*
2. Click on the green plus icon
3. Select *Django tests*
4. Optionally enter the Django app name in the *Target* field (`lists` in your case)

If you have configured your django project and python interpreter in your PyCharm settings it should work.

Hope this helps.