# Unable to set up Jinja2 with Django

Tags: django, jinja2

I've installed Django 1.9.7, and I have Pythons 3.4.3 and 2.7.10 on Ubuntu.

These are the steps I've followed:

1. Made a new project with `django-admin startproject testproject`
2. `cd testproject/testproject`
3. Made an app within the project with `django-admin startapp testapp`
4. Made a directory for templates in that app with `mkdir testapp/templates` and added a very basic `index.html` template in there
5. Edited `settings.py` to change the template backend to `django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2`, by editing line 57 of the default settings file, and to add `testproject.testapp` to `INSTALLED_APPS`; the `TEMPLATES` section is therefore like this:

   ```
   TEMPLATES = [
       {
           'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
           'DIRS': [],
           'APP_DIRS': True,
           'OPTIONS': {
               'context_processors': [
                   'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                   'django.template.context_processors.request',
                   'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                   'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
               ],
           },
       },
   ]
   ```
6. Edited `urls.py`, adding `from testproject.testapp import views` and a URL pattern `url(r'^$', views.index),`
7. Edited `testapp/views.py` adding

   ```
   def index(request):
       return render(request, 'index.html')
   ```
8. `cd ..`
9. Ran the server with `python3 manage.py runserver`, or `python manage.py runserver` -- very similar effect
10. Take a browser to `http://localhost:3000`

I get an error. On the command line I get this:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 86, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'jinja2'
```

Followed by another exception caused "during handling of the above exception", which matches the exception I see in the browser:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/

Django Version: 1.9.7
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.staticfiles', 'testproject.testapp', 'webpack_loader']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/utils.py" in __getitem__
  86.             return self._engines[alias]

During handling of the above exception ('jinja2'), another exception occurred:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  174.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  172.                     response = response.render()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  160.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  135.         template = self._resolve_template(self.template_name)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in _resolve_template
  90.         new_template = self.resolve_template(template)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in resolve_template
  80.             return select_template(template, using=self.using)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in select_template
  55.     engines = _engine_list(using)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in _engine_list
  143.     return engines.all() if using is None else [engines[using]]

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/utils.py" in all
  110.         return [self[alias] for alias in self]

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/utils.py" in <listcomp>
  110.         return [self[alias] for alias in self]

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/utils.py" in __getitem__
  101.             engine = engine_cls(params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/backends/jinja2.py" in __init__
  35.         self.env = environment_cls(**options)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_processors'
```

I get very similar traces with Python 2.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566182/django-templates-and-apps-not-loading) which has a similar error message (`KeyError: 'jinja2'`) but seems to be a separate problem, and [this bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24265) which has the same error again whose solution is to install jinja2, but jinja2 is definitely installed. At least, I can run `python` or `python3` and then `import jinja2`. `pip` says jinja2 is up to date.

I must be missing something crucial -- any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you have changed the default template backend from django to jinja - it would be better to add Jinja as an additional backend (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701631/how-to-use-jinja2-as-a-templating-engine-in-django-1-8). If you replace the Django template backend, then apps that use Django templates won't work any more, including the admin.

Comment: Also, Django will look for Jinja templates in `testapp/jinja2`, not `testapp/templates`.

Comment: `mv testproject/testapp/templates testproject/testapp/jinja2` didn't change anything (I think it's not even getting as far as trying to find the specified template), but that's useful to know; thanks. I then rolled back the template backend settings to stock and then added a new entry for Jinja2 as you suggested, but omitted the options key from the linked answer completely (since I don't yet know what Environment does) and left DIRS empty (since APP_DIRS will do what I want), and it now works. If you write this an an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I was specific in the question that it was all default other than what I changed. `context_processors` was there by default -- I hadn't touched it since I didn't know what it was. The documentation isn't very clear when it comes to Jinja2, and what I understood from it was that all I had to do was change the `BACKEND`.

Comment: Bu,the documentation for Jinja2 is [very comprehensive](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2), showing exactly what options are allowed; context_processors is not one of them.

Comment: That's true. I confess I hadn't looked to the Jinja2 docs, only to the Django ones.

Comment: I feel the downvote is unfair. Would the downvoter remove that if I include the (mis)configuration which was asked for in a deleted comment?

Comment: I've made that edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error about `context_processors` is because the Jinja2 backend does not support that argument.

You should add an additional backend to your `TEMPLATES` setting, rather than replacing the existing backend from django to `jinja2`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701631/how-to-use-jinja2-as-a-templating-engine-in-django-1-8) for more information. If you replace the existing backend, then apps that require Django templates will not work, including the admin.

Finally, the jinja2 backend will look for templates in `testapp/jinja2`, not `testapp/templates`.