# PyCharm: Options of non-pure python project (e.g. Django) not available

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm

I am trying to create Django project. According to the tutorial, the possible selections like below should show up when I try to create a new project:

[image]

However, when I did File -> New Project, the window I got was:

[image]

Any idea what was missing? Thanks!

Comment: If I recall correctly the community edition of PyCharm only supports pure Python projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do check if you are using pycharm CE or Community Edition. If so then you cannot do a direct django project from it. If you are a student you can register in jetbrains website and get the pycharm complete edition for free for a year. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

You can start your django project from command line and then open that folder in pycharm CE and it should work well.

Please check this answer for more clarity. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23870582/9544403